# Makefiles and large projects with complex interdependencies

Tags: build, makefile, dependencies, gnu-make

I am trying to come up with a build system for a large project that has a structure like this:

```
├── deploy
├── docs
├── libs
│   ├── lib1
│   └── lib2
├── scripts
└── tools
    ├── prog1
    └── prog2
```

My problem is that libs and programs may depend on each other in an order that may change very often. I have looked up info on the internet and I get mixed messages. Some people say that I should just use makefiles and some other say that recursive makefiles are evil.

Besides that, I don't know how to manage dependencies with makefiles (if `lib2` needs `lib1` to build, how to tell make to build `lib1` first). Someone told me that it is easily achievable using the variable `VPATH` but I have read the documentation and I think it has nothing to do with this.

So my questions are:

- Should I really avoid makefiles in this case? If so, what are the alternatives?
- If I should use makefiles, how can I manage dependencies automatically and efficiently?

Comment: Yes, you should avoid GNU make. Working alternatives (not the freshest list): cmake, scons and jam. If you know Perl: pcons 2.3. If you want to stick with make then at least take the BSD make instead (pmake or bmake on Linux systems).

Comment: "Avoid GNU make" and go for pmake or bmake is bad advice.  If you stay with make, GNU make is the most portable, most widely-used version, it has a significant user's manual, many books written for it, and it'll be the easiest to get help with.  When people say "recursive makefiles are evil" they aren't necessarily saying "don't use make"; they're saying if you use make then consider writing your makefiles in a non-recursive way.  I agree VPATH is not directly helpful for that.

Comment: If you don't want to write your own makefiles, then cmake (very cross-platform) and automake (doesn't work so well on Windows) will generate makefiles for you using simpler input constructs.  Both have their own complexities and learning curve.  cmake can generate more than just makefiles: it can generate Eclipse project files, Xcode project files, Visual Studio project files, and various others.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I am in the *don't lie to make* camp.
Here,
fine-grained dependencies are your friend.
Get away from thinking that you need to express that *prog1* depends on *lib2*. What you really want to say to *make* is something like:

"To link *prog1* you need all the `.o` files, and all the appropriate `.a` files."

If you can express this,
it will improve a number of very important parameters for your build:

1. Parallel build works properly

   - The `.o` file for `prog1` can compile at the same time as those for 
     `lib2.a`
   - This is more important if you run tests as a part of the build
     (you do do that, don't you?)
2. Time-to-do-nothing is very close to zero

   - Nothing worse than issuing a build,
     and several minutes later you get a
     *build was already up-to-date* (WinCE, I'm looking at you)
3. Work is properly culled

   - In other words you can rely on your dependencies,
     and never have to do a *make clean* because you don't trust them

After all,
these goals are really the whole point of using *make*.
Get them wrong and you might as well use a batch file.
(It's pretty tricky getting them right in a recursive make system BTW.)

Of course,
expressing this cleanly in *make* does take a bit of effort,
but you did say you had a *large* project.

Comment: Amazing. Thanks for that advice.

Comment: So are you also arguing against recursive makefiles? Or do you think it doesn't really matter if you get your dependencies right?

Comment: @exilit It's pretty (_really_) hard to get fine-grained dependencies working in a recursive make system. Definitely not a fan. In fact my advice would be to avoid at all costs.

Answer (score 1):

I'm not in the recursive makefiles are evil camp -- while it's true that recursive makefiles are not as efficient (they don't maximize concurrency, etc), it's usually negligible.   On the flip side, using recursive makefiles makes your project more scalable -- it's simpler to move modules in and out, share with other groups, etc.

In your case, if lib2 depends on lib1, you can just do:

```
 lib2: lib1
    make -C libs/lib2
```

Now make will build lib1 before lib2 (even if you have -j specified).

Now if you have cross-dependencies (something in lib1 depends on something in lib2, which in turn depends on something else in lib1), then you might want to consider either restructuring your directories to avoid the cross-dependencies, or using a single makefile (there's lots of sharp sticks exposed if you try to use recursive makefiles in this case).